# How to create multiple modals to display different data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to create multiple modals to show different data. Ive looked at other examples (on stack overflow), and implemented the code and it is still not working for me. Basically at this point I'm just looking to get it to work and have copied the script off the WW3 Schools webpage. I have two examples...one with just one modal (which works) and then the second with two modals (which should display different data (that doesn't work). But when i delete the first modal the second modal works. Ive included the whole page just in case its another issue, Ive also inspected the elements and its saying there is no errors. I hope that you can help me!

First Example with one modal (works).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Modals</title>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

My second example with two modals is below. (doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Modals</title>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

    <h2>Modal Example 3</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the variables (btn, modal) and the onlick event you defined for the first modal.

You can solve the problem by renaming the variables of your second modal (e.g.: modal2, btn2 etc.).

Also you should define the `window.onclick` event once and check for each modal like this:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here is a quick jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yccvpng/

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me, this is my first time using modals and Im still in the early stages of coding!